# how to convert list into separate strings?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a below list:

```
my_list = ["apple", "banana", "mango"]
```

and I need below output

```
"apple", "banana", "mango"
```

I tried below code so far.

```
output = ",".join('"' + item.strip() + '"' for item in my_list)
print(output)
```

How can convert it like so that len(Output) should be 3 instead of 24:

```
"apple","banana","mango"
```

Comment: You would have to derive a class from `list` with its own `__str__` representation code if you want it to have `len` 3 here.

Comment: That deosn't make any sense Sachin....why you need length to be `3` ? once brackets are removed it will become a string ... No way it's length would be `3` ...

Comment: I am trying to pass them as a positional arguments to a function which accepts 3 arguments. But I am getting error "IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple"

Comment: You don't need to do such string manipulation to pass positional arguments. You can do `some_function(*my_list)`

Comment: This is called an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are printing the entire list, you can modify the code as:

```
my_list = ["apple", "banana", "mango"]

output = ", ".join('"' + item.strip() + '"' for item in my_list)
print(output)
print(len(my_list))
```

Here, you just get the length of list, and I also added a space after the comma.

If you want to pass them to a function you can just pass the list and index.

```
def function(my_list):
    print(my_list[1])

function(my_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

> I am trying to pass them as a positional arguments to a function which accepts 3 arguments

Simply use `f(*my_list)`:

```
def f(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print('First arg is', arg1)
    print('Second arg is', arg2)
    print('Third arg is', arg3)
```

Usage:

```
>>> f(*my_list)
First arg is apple
Second arg is banana
Third arg is mango
```

You can also reverse the pattern:

```
def f(*args):
    for i, arg in enumerate(*args, 1):  # <- not the *args to expand args
        print(f'Arg {i} is {arg}')
```

Usage:

```
>>> f(my_list)
Arg 1 is apple
Arg 2 is banana
Arg 3 is mango
```